# E: Unable to locate packages libsqli

Tags: ruby, command-line, package

I'm installing ruby on Xubuntu but before actually installing ruby I needed to install some packages and libraries. so I ran the command

> sudo apt-get install curl git nodejs gcc make libssl-dev libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev libsql

and I got this output with an error:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package libsqli

Any idea on how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the built-in repositories that are listed in the `sources.list`. Your system can't find required package.

You have to update it.

For example

```
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Highly recommend to [follow instructions](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/18.04) from special site.

You can choose rvm/rbenv, versions of OS, Ruby, Rails

This tutorial will help you to configure Git, PostgreSQL